# How to call a service binder from MainActivity through a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-service, onclicklistener

I'm setting an OnClickListener to cardviews on my ViewHolder:

```
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mBoundString = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mTextView.setText(mValues.get(position));

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {


                MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();
                mActivity.onClickPlayButton(v);
            }
        });

        Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
                .load(Stations.getRandomCheeseDrawable())
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.mImageView);
    }
```

This is my onClickPlayButton on MainActivity:

```
public void onClickPlayButton(View view) {
        radioServiceBinder.play();
    }
```

This is the Service code:

```
public class RadioService extends Service implements OnErrorListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnInfoListener {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private List<String> radioStreamURL = new ArrayList<>();
private int radioStreamingIndex = 0;

public static final String MODE_CREATED = "CREATED";
public static final String MODE_DESTROYED = "DESTROYED";
public static final String MODE_PREPARED = "PREPARED";
public static final String MODE_STARTED = "STARTED";
public static final String MODE_PLAYING = "PLAYING";
public static final String MODE_PAUSED = "PAUSED";
public static final String MODE_STOPPED = "STOPPED";
public static final String MODE_COMPLETED = "COMPLETED";
public static final String MODE_ERROR = "ERROR";
public static final String MODE_BUFFERING_START = "BUFFERING_START";
public static final String MODE_BUFFERING_END = "BUFFERING_END";

private boolean isPrepared = false;

private final IBinder binder = new RadioBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // add stations to the list

        radioStreamURL.add("http://momori.animenfo.com:8000/");
        radioStreamURL.add("http://momori.animenfo.com:8000/");
        radioStreamURL.add("http://momori.animenfo.com:8000/");

        /* Create MediaPlayer when it starts for first time */
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_CREATED));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        isPrepared = false;
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_DESTROYED));
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STARTED));

        /* Starts playback at first time or resumes if it is restarted */
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PLAYING));
        else if(isPrepared) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PAUSED));
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        /* If radio is prepared then start playback */
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PREPARED));
        isPrepared = true;
        play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        /* When no stream found then complete the playback */
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        isPrepared = false;
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_COMPLETED));
    }

    public void prepare() {
        /* Prepare Async Task - starts buffering */
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioStreamURL.get(radioStreamingIndex));
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void nextStation(){
        changeStation(radioStreamingIndex+1);
    }

    public void prevStation(){
        changeStation(radioStreamingIndex-1);
    }

    public void changeStation(int stationIndex){
        if(stationIndex > 0 && stationIndex < radioStreamURL.size()){
            radioStreamingIndex = stationIndex;
            stop();
            play();
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        if(isPrepared) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            System.out.println("RadioService: play");
            //sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PLAYING));
        }
        else
        {
            //sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STARTED));
            prepare();
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        System.out.println("RadioService: pause");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PAUSED));
    }

    public void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        isPrepared = false;
        System.out.println("RadioService: stop");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STOPPED));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        /* Check when buffering is started or ended */
        if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_BUFFERING_START));
        }
        else if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_BUFFERING_END));
        }

        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_ERROR));
        switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                Log.v("ERROR","MEDIA ERROR NOT VALID FOR PROGRESSIVE PLAYBACK " + extra);
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                Log.v("ERROR","MEDIA ERROR SERVER DIED " + extra);
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                Log.v("ERROR","MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN " + extra);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    /* Allowing activity to access all methods of RadioService */
    public class RadioBinder extends Binder {
        RadioService getService() {
            // Return this instance of RadioService so clients can call public methods
            return RadioService.this;
        }
    }

}
```

When I click it, I got this error on logcat: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ....RadioService.play()' on a null object reference.

I don't think there is anything wrong in the play() method.

I want the OnClickListener or the onClickPlayButton to call the play() method from my Service class that is binded to my MainActivity. How can I achieve this?
I'm stuck at this problem.

Comment: I assume your `ViewHolder` belongs to an adapter which belongs to your `Fragment` which is within your `MainActivity`? Pass the fragments `Context` to your `ViewHolder` and call there `((MainActivity) context.getActivity()).onClickPlayButton(v)`.

Comment: Yes. I'm gonna try this and post the results here.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kphil, there is no `getActivity()` method in class `Context`. Yours code should be without it: `((MainActivity) context).onClickPlayButton(v);` See my updated answer;

Comment: My bad, pass the context from your `Fragment` via `getActivity()` to your adapter, an than call your activity method like mohax posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Yours error here

```
MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();
mActivity.onClickPlayButton(v);
```

You try to call method of new instance of Activitys class. But you should call method of current, running instance of yours activity. So you must send reference to yours activity to adapter and call yours method on it.

As I understand, you initialize variables and bind yours Service in OnCreate or onResume of yours activity. But this methods not invoked adter you create a new instance of MainActivity class;

**UPD_0:**

So yours adapters class should be like this:

```
public class YOURS_ADAPTERS_CLASS_NAME extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YOURS_ADAPTERS_CLASS_NAME.ViewHolder>
{
    Context ctx;

public YOURS_ADAPTERS_CLASS_NAME(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
}

///other lines of yours code
```

So now you have instance of yours running activity inside yours adapters class. You now should cast it to yours activitys class and call yours method this way:

```
 MainActivity mActivity= (MainActivity) ctx;
 mActivity.onClickPlayButton(v);
```

Also, you don't need (as i can see) an argument in method `onClickPlayButton()`

Comment: Thanks for helping me.
I tried this instead:

MainActivity.radioServiceBinder.play();

But the radioServiceBinder is a non-Static field, and it cannot be refenced from a static content